# Sharepoint PNP For Developer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, p-np

I work on **SharePoint programming**. I recently became acquainted with a topic called Sharepoin Pnp . **What is the nature of sharepoint pnp?** When should it be used? What is the connection with **Web Part** and other SharePoint Programming Parts like **CSOM** with sharepoint pnp? Thanks for the advice of your dear friends.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP) is an open source initiative coordinated by SharePoint engineering. It is also a Client Side library which is similiar with CSOM. But it's open source and monthly update.

There is three type library for PnP, Js,C# and PowerShell, you can choose the one you want to use.

For Web Parts, here is the instance which can connect and handle web part:
[image]

More information, please refer:

[PnP PowerShell overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)